# Android get files list from DCIM

Tags: java, android, directory

I want to get all files list from DCIM directory, but I don’t know why, it does not work.
I’m using the examples below but no data.

```
Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
```

or

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

I’ve tried other options too but no way. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Have you set the adequate permission in your manifest ? If so can you elaborate more about what you tried ?

Answer (score 9):

To retrieve the content of that `Directory` you can use

```
File dcim = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
if (dcim != null) {
  File[] pics = dcim.listFiles();
  if (pics != null) {
     for (File pic : pics) {
     }
  }
}
```

Be aware that `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` could not exist yet.

**Edit:**

Starting from `API level 19`, Android enforces the use of `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to access folders on the public storage. From the documentation:

> This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level
>   19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to
>   read from external storage. You can test your app with the permission
>   enforced by enabling Protect USB storage under Developer options in
>   the Settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.

You can add  either it or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, as pointed out by @JordiCastilla, which will grant you both reading and writing access to the directory

Comment: Maybe add also permissions info? OP does not mention it in question

Comment: @JordiCastilla the documentation doesn't mention anything about any needed use-permission to access that directory. Could you please share a link ? Thanks for the input tough

Comment: Sure. AFAIK, `DCIM` **is** External Storage so `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` are required as mentioned in [android storage documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) and [Manifest permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE). Hope it helps ;)

Comment: you are right, since api 19 to read it is compulsory the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. I had forgot about that. Thanks @JordiCastilla

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I've tried the example you provided, the problem is that I need to list DCIM Camera directory (maybe didn't explain correctly)
Is there any example please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: and what is it returning ?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM but when trying to access here or just fot to check if folder contains some another folder and/or file, it returns null ((

Comment: Did you add the permission in the manifest? Can you update your question with the code you are using?

Comment: The code is the same as in the example above.
`code`
File dcim = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
if (dcim != null) {
  File[] pics = dcim.listFIles();
  if (pics != null) {
     for (File pic : pics) {
Log.d("Image:" + pic.getName());
     }
  }
}
`code`
and the manifest permission is

`code`
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
`code`

Comment: You mean the snippet I posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89725/discussion-between-user2137580-and-blackbelt).

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution to read SD Card DCIM directory. Maybe it is not very good option one however the example is:

```
String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
File images = new File(secStore+"/DCIM/Camera");
```

Then you get images list with images.List();

Hope will help someone.

Thanks all and Regards

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something similar